# How to use Azure AD goups authorization in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, authorization

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application which should authenticate with an external identity provider (Azure Active Directory).

I want to authorize application with Azure AD groups or roles - how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP Core Azure Active Directory Login use roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926083/asp-core-azure-active-directory-login-use-roles)

Comment: @SergiyMatvienko Asp.net  Core it's easy just add gorup policy in ur app service i want authorizaion with asp.net framework MVC 5